# How to make Apache check if PHP file exists before passing it to PHP-FPM?

Tags: apache, php

I get the following error "No input file specified." instead of a file not found when I request a non-existent PHP file.

So is it possible to make Apache check if PHP file exists before passing it to the PHP-FPM server to avoid "No input file specified." error? or that error is normal/harmless?

This is how Apache is configured to handle PHP files:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock.example|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dislike using the RewriteEngine for that task. Here is the correct configuration to use a SetHandler directive, while checking that the PHP file actually exists :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|php[57]|phtml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Source : [PHP-FPM](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM)

Comment: Your example here lacks the `<Proxy>` directive in that article. Also, are there any concerns about the security issues he mentions?

Comment: To prevent 503 error, I had to add : <Else> SetHandler default-handler </Else>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mod_rewrite (virtual host context) alternative recipe that only sets the Handler if the file exists.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [H=proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/]
```

But it would not work with PATH_INFO as-is because it would check for the file+path info under the document root

Comment: Could you expand on the PATH_INFO comment please?

Comment: IIUC, one advantage of configuring this with SetHandler in <Files> is that Apache will calculate path_info properly for you and pass it to PHP-FPM.  PATH_INFO is the non query string stuff that follows your script name -- like /foo.php/bar/baz or /foo/bar/baz when /foo is mapped to /foo.php.

Comment: @covener This can be easily addressed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all requests for a PHP script (even if the script don't exists on the filesystem) will be passed in the proxy_fcgi handler.. One way to fix this issue (Apache >= 2.4.10 required) is to put the following in your Apache2 vhost file:

```
# define worker
<Proxy "unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-domain.tld.sock|fcgi://domain.tld" retry=0>
    ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

<FilesMatch \.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .* - [H=proxy:fcgi://domain.tld,NC]
</FilesMatch>
```

Here, we set the **proxy_fcgi** handler only if the file exists. The **PATH_INFO** is correctly handled too. Note that we must inherite rewrite rules (case of rewrite rules that are stored in .htaccess file).